# libgdx change background when game reset

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to change my background after three attempts from day to night and back again after three attempts. I have put an integer in the gamerenderer class.
I created two methods drawDAY and drawNight.

I want to change by GAMEOVER or HIGHSCORE.
Any idea how to set this up in GameWorld?

```
public void changeBG(int x){
    if(x == 3){
        drawDAY();}
    else if (x == 6){
        drawNIGHT();}
        x = 0;
    }

private void drawNIGHT() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void drawDAY() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to store the current number of attempted tries in the Preferences, like so

```
private static Preferences preferences; 

@Override
public void create()
{
    preferences = Gdx.app.getPreferences(Resources.preferencesName);
    ...

public static Preferences getPreferences()
{
    return preferences;
}
```

Where you add the number as the following:

```
    int currentTries = MyGame.getPreferences().getInt("numberOfTries");
    currentTries++;
    currentTries %= 6;
    MyGame.getPreferences().putInt("numberOfTries", currentTries);
    MyGame.getPreferences().flush();
```

Afterwards, what you want to do is check the current try count:

```
 public void changeBG(int x){
    if(x < 3) {
        drawDAY();
    }
    else if (x < 6) {
        drawNIGHT();
    }
 }
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. I'm new with java and try to learn it.I would like to appreciate some explanation. I want my game changed from day to night at GAMEOVER or RETRY after three attempts.
I can also create two textures (texture1 and texture2) with day and NIGHT with the same with textureRegions for all of the images instead of the day and night background, which change after three attempts.

Comment: If you get to GAMEOVER or RETRY, you need to execute the second code segment to increase the total number of tries. The code makes it so that you store the number between 0...5, and you call the drawDay or drawNight depending on that number. What you ACTUALLY need though is to set the texture region of the background from the day's TextureRegion to the night's TextureRegion. If the background is stored in a Sprite, that should be simple.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will look at it later. sorry but I have to go to my work. Greetings.

Comment: My goal was to make sure the application always remembers the number of tries, so that even if you quit and restart it remembers if it's day and night :)

Comment: I'll formulate my previous question again with a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057817/libgdx-change-background-after-three-attempts