# libgdx change background after three attempts

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx

I'll formulate my previous question again. I want the background of my game change from day to night. This should be done after two or three tries to play the game.
I have óne texture with different textureRegions for the day and the night. 
Any help is very much appreciated.
I work with eclipse.

this is what a have in my AssetLoader.java

```
DAY= new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 287, 512);
DAY.flip(false, true);
NIGHT= new TextureRegion(texture, 291, 0, 287,512);
NIGHT.flip(false, true);
```

This is what a have in my GameRenderer.java

```
public void changeBG(int x){
if(x < 3){
drawDAY();
} 
else if (x < 6)
{
drawNIGHT();
}
}
private void drawNIGHT() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
 private void drawDAY() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub}
}
```

This is what i have in my GameWorld.java

```
  public void update(float delta) {
   runTime += delta;

   switch (currentState) {
   case READY:
   case MENU:
         updateReady(delta);
         break;
   case RUNNING:
         updateRunning(delta);
         break;
   default:
      break;
   }
     }
public boolean isReady() {
     return currentState == GameState.READY;
  }
```

I hope this is enough information.
Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Lets say you have a Sprite that holds the whole texture.

```
Sprite timeOfDay = new Sprite(texture);
```

Then by simply tweaking your changeBG(int x) method. You can appropriately set the sprite to the Region you want.

```
public void changeBG(int x){
    if(x < 5) //Assuming x is the time
        timeOfDay.setRegion(DAY);
    else
        timeOfDay.setRegion(NIGHT);
}
```

and then in your draw() method after you set the batch up

```
timeOfDay.draw(batch);
```

I hope this helps.

[Update]

No need to draw DAY and NIGHT in your render method. Time of Day holds the DAY and NIGHT textures. When you call

```
timeOfDay.draw(batch);
```

it renders the setRegion.

Your render should look something like this....

```
public void draw(){
    batcher.begin();
    timeOfDay.draw(batcher);
    batcher.end();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm not quite familiar with java and libgdx.So any help will be appreciated by me.This is what I have now,in my AssetLoader.... Sprite timeOfDay = new Sprite(texture); 
 
 public void changeBG(int x) {
 
 if (x < 5)
  timeOfDay.setRegion(DAY);
 else
  timeOfDay.setRegion(NIGHT);
  
 }

Comment: And in my GameRenderer....DAY.setRegion(291, 0, 287, 512);
  DAY.flip(false, true);
  batcher.draw(DAY, 0, midPointY -120, 136, 243);
        
  NIGHT.setRegion(0, 0, 287, 512);
  NIGHT.flip(false, true);
  batcher.draw(NIGHT, 0, midPointY -120, 136, 243);
     timeOfDay.draw(batcher);  Please need some help.

Comment: Hi compulsivestudios thanks for the help. I still have problems. When I'm in my render the draw method places I get an error. under timeOfDay. and when i run i have no background at all. The game plays but no background. public void draw() {
     batcher.begin();
  timeOfDay.draw(batcher);
     batcher.end();
 }

Comment: As a debug, try setting the timeOfDay Region to DAY in the init somewhere. That way you know that the timeOfDay is being set as DAY by default

Answer (score 0):

As I've partially said in the previous answer, what you need to do from scratch is pretty much the following:

```
DAY= new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 287, 512);
DAY.flip(false, true);
NIGHT= new TextureRegion(texture, 291, 0, 287,512);
NIGHT.flip(false, true);
```

Then you create a Sprite:

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(DAY);
```

I'm guessing you will set it to the size of the screen, which depends on whether you use Scene2d or an Orthogonal transform or just go at it plainly with screen coordinates:

```
sprite.setSize(Gdx.graphics.width, Gdx.graphics.height);
```

or

```
sprite.setSize(virtualWidth, virtualHeight); //in new version of LibGDX this is standard 640x480
```

And afterwards, based on the logic of the game, you will want to change the TextureRegion. To store how many times you've retried, you need to use the Preferences:

```
private static Preferences preferences; 

@Override
public void create()
{
    preferences = Gdx.app.getPreferences(Resources.preferencesName);
    ...

public static Preferences getPreferences()
{
    return preferences;
}
```

After which when the game ended, you do the following:

Where you add the number as the following at a game over to change the number of tries:

```
    int currentTries = MyGame.getPreferences().getInt("numberOfTries");
    currentTries++;
    currentTries %= 6;
    MyGame.getPreferences().putInt("numberOfTries", currentTries);
    MyGame.getPreferences().flush();
    changeBG(currentTries);
```

And then you change the current texture region:

```
 public void changeBG(int x){
    if(x < 3) {
        sprite.setRegion(DAY);
    }
    else if (x < 6) {
        sprite.setRegion(NIGHT);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Zhuinden, this is what i have now:
private static Preferences preferences;
 
 public void create()
 {
        prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("JoopklepsGame");
        
        int currentTries = Gdx.app.getPreferences("JoopklepsGame").getInteger("numberOfTries");
        currentTries++;
        currentTries %= 6;
        Gdx.app.getPreferences("JoopklepsGame").putInteger("numberOfTries", currentTries);
        Gdx.app.getPreferences("JoopklepsGame").flush();
        changeBG(currentTries); 
}
 public static Preferences getPreferences()
 {
        return preferences;
    }

Comment: Where put sprite.setSize???


I put everything in my assetloader, i use Eclipse.

greetings Jooklep.

Comment: After the creation of the Sprite, if I know correctly. But if you use the AssetManager, then you should post the code so we can figure it out together, as I did not use that in my project.

Comment: Thanks for the support Zhuinden, I got no errors but it does not work this way. Maybe I should try something with de random method. with two textures. A DAY and a NIGHT texture, (texture1)(texture2) Maybe you can help here, think about it.Most goto work now.Maybe until later. ;-)

Comment: Noooooo having two textures is not a good idea, having one texture is the best. What do you mean "not working"?

Comment: Hi Zhuinden maybe I make it difficult for myself. I will explain it again. I want to make something like the old flappybird game. Not the same, of course, but with the same principle where the background changed from day to night and night to day. Also the characters and objects must also change. I have a texture with characters and objects with different textureRegions.Thank you. ;-)

Comment: I put everything in my renderer and this is what a get;Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion.setRegion(TextureRegion.java:112) etc...

Comment: Now i put everthing in my assetLoader and no errors but no change from day to night.

Comment: Can you throw the relevant code to my email address at my name @ gmail.com so I can take an exact look at it?

Comment: Right, I didn't notice in your new posted code that you did not make sure that the Preferences is a singleton object.